# Stopping ReportServer execution logs Deletion

Tags: reporting-services, reportserver

My ReportServer execution logs are deleted after 60 days. I want to deactive it.

With this command

```
Update ConfigurationInfo SET Value='90' 
Where NAME='ExecutionLogDaysKept'
```

My question is. Is this enough or do I need really execute the following command as well? If "yes" then why?

```
EXEC ReportServer.dbo.ExpireExecutionLogEntries
```

Comment: I would normally change this from the Server Properties Window in SSMS, connect to the Report Services service and the right-click the server.

Comment: Without using the Procedure?

Comment: yes, I think that proc just removes anything older than the retention period but as it looks like you are extending the number of days it would not do anything anyway.

Comment: I hope you are right